# Is this function computable?

Tags: computer-science, computability

Given the function

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x = W(M)$ is the encoding of a turing machine $M$ and $M$ halts if the empty word is entered } \\
undefined, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is it computable? $f$ is defined on $\Bbb N$. I think one of the problem here is to decide whether some $x$ is indeed the encoding of a turing machine or not. I don't see how one should be able to decide something like that.

On the other hand, if we know that something is the encoding of a turing machine, it should be pretty easy to decide whether the turing machine halts if the empty word is entered, although I'm not sure how to formalise this.

The function being undefined isn't a problem, this can be achieved by defining a loop.

Comment: How is it easy to decide whether a turing machin holds? What *is* easy is to build a turing machine to execute `for (n=4; ; n+=2) if (n is not the sum of two primes) halt;` Now you tell me if that halts ...  I suppose you may want to dig deeper into how to exploit the fact that "undefined" is the other value

Comment: So we actually can't tell if the turing machine holds?

Comment: About the undefined value: I would just go about it like this: if: (...) else: while (x >= 0) x = x or something like that. This leads to the function being undefined, I guess.

Comment: By "holds" do you mean "halts?" (Re: "I think one of the problem here is to decide whether some x is indeed the encoding of a turing machine or not. I don't see how one should be able to decide something like that.", it is in fact a good exercise to show that the set of codes of Turing machines is computable; this is usually done explicitly before constructing a universal machine, so you might check your notes.)

Comment: I mean "halts", yes, sorry.